# Cannot call onDraw(Canvas canvas) with update()

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw, invalidation

I'm currently developing android and went into a very serious problem :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.i("GAME", "onDraw Called");
    for(int i = 0; i < totalEggNumbers -1; i++) {
        if (egg[i].isKilled = false)
        canvas.drawBitmap(image[egg[i].getEggNum()], egg[i].getX(), egg[i].getY() + 100, paint);
        Log.i("GAME", "Something Drawn");
    }
}

// called by thread
public void update() {
        //Chance to make egg
    Log.i("GAME", "Updated Game");
    eggMaker.randomEgg(difficulty);
    postInvalidate();
}
```

The `onDraw` never gets called and I cant find the log in logcat after I terminated the app, but when it is running, I could see one "onDraw Called" showing up and disappearing occasionally.

Im really desperate... I am using android view btw. Any way to call the `onDraw` method? I tried `invalidate();` and no chance, please modify my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your image as BitMap object before passing it to the drawBitMap methode

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        getResources(), image[egg[i].getEggNum());
```

Comment: I looking something similar , but i am sure .Android canvas does not work like canvas JS . No need for call onDraw , just set      ViewGroup view;
        view = (ViewGroup) findViewById( R.id.YOURID );
        view.setWillNotDraw(false);